# Parent and child selection, can't access first parent (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, parent, children

I have a problem with a parent/child selection with jquery.

I have a HTML page who looks like this:

```
<tr> 
   <input type='checkbox' /> //1st checkbox
   <.. some stuff ../>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type='checkbox' /></td> //2nd checkbox
   <td>
     <select id='stateChanger' onchange='stateChanger();'/>
       <option> ...</option>
       ...
   </td> 
</tr>
```

> I want to check the checkbox of the line I changed with my select at the moment I changed it. But with the code hereinbelow I only check the first checkbox.

```
function stateChanger(){

        $('#stateChanger').parent().parent().children('td').children("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked","true");
}
```

If anyone has idea to help me, I can post the full code.
Thanks. Victor

Comment: try `stateChanger(this)` and then `function stateChanger(obj){$(obj).closest("tr").find("td:first input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked","true")`

Comment: After fixing the HTML, the jQuery line does exactly what it's supposed to do: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/0svt6k8m/ (although you'll want to use `prop` instead of `attr`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
function stateChanger(obj) {
  $(obj).closest("tr").find("td:first input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked", "true")
}
```

and add `this` to `onchange='stateChanger();'` so it will be `onchange='stateChanger(this);'`

This will check the second `<input type='checkbox' />`

**demo**

```js
function stateChanger(obj) {
  $(obj).closest("tr").find("td:first input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked", "true")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <input type='checkbox' />
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
    <td>
      <select id='stateChanger' onchange='stateChanger(this);' />
      <option> ...</option>
      <option>texst</option>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I just had to remove the colon in the find and replace it with a white space.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#stateChanger').closest('tr').find("td input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked","true");
```

`closest()` finds the nearest parent of the target element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like following

```js
function stateChanger(){
    $('#stateChanger').closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
}
```

```css
table td{ border:1px solid #999; }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr> 
        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
        <td>
            <select id='stateChanger' onchange='stateChanger();'>
                <option value="0">Select Value</option>
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            </select>
        </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```